# The Breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols where loaded for this document

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2013, breakpoints

Windows 8, VS2013 IIS8,5

I'm trying to connect to a local WEB API by connecting to processes w3pv.exe (Managed (v4.0.30319), 19). The website front end and back end is both running fine on my local IIS. Right after publishing my x86 web API to the local IIS i try to connect to the process, where the break point states "The Breakpoints will not currently be hit. No symbols where loaded for this document". My colleague' can without any problems debug from his local computer.

So far I have.

1. Reinstalled VS2013.
2. Checked All Debug Properties

   -Project -> build: Define DEBUG constant check / Define TRACE constant       check.

   - Generate serialization assembly = Auto. Advanced build settings -> Debug info = full
   - Enable Just My Code: Check, Use Managed Compatibility Mode: Check
   - Enable Edit and Continue : Check
3. Made sure all Debug mode is set and all project Configured to Active solution platform x86, marked Debug and Build.
4. Deleted all bin and obj folders, as well as pdb folder in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
5. Reset IIS.
6. Set Select Code Type to Automatically determine the type of code to debug
7. Checked in IIS that .Net compilation -> Debug and Enable Prefetch is set to true.

And I still get the same error message. Anyone found anything in addition to this?

[image]
  [image]
  [image]

Comment: Have you compared your settings to those of your colleague? Are they the same? Do you have the same VS/IIS software versions and updates?

Comment: When I came across this problem, the solution for me was to make sure I have attached the right services/process for debugging. That ctrl+alt+P (attach to process) thing on VS.

Comment: Show us the publish settings please

Comment: Settings are fully compared and identical. I'm using IIS 8,5 anad he's using IIS 7,5, but still most properties are the same.  

(Ctrl+alt+P) opens the attatch to process window, where I find the w3wp.exe file, with the type "Managed (v4.0.30319), x64" and User Name "IIS APPPOOL\scout", which is the name of the APPPOOL in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered similar problems many times while training new employees in our very complicated devenv, so here is our internal step by step instruction:

1. Don't panic
2. Make sure you attached the debugger to the correct process - you debug the plugin by launching VMS which is external app that has separate config file where the plugin path is stored, so when you change just your configuration Debug/Release it doesn't work.
3. Make sure you have symbols generated for the assembly Project properties->Build->Advanced->Output section
4. Make sure the build path hasn't changed. You may have accidentally changed the path and you may only think that the assembly you are trying to debug is the correct one.

Investigating the information you provided this is only help I can think of. My guess is the files you publish are not the files you're debugging locally.

Comment: 1. Less Panic initiated.
2. What do you mean by "debug the plugin"? 
3. The api is being sent to a bin folder upon publish. This is the same folder as the IIS referrers to. In other words, when I delete that folder, the website stops working. When I delete the folder, and re-publish, the website works again, but still debugging does not. 
4.  My build path is now set to bin\ folder. That's the same folder as it has always been. 

Thank you for your help

Comment: This was our internal instruction so step 2 does not concern you. Unfortunately, my steps are useless in your case, but I see you found out what the problem was so good for you:)

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED (embarrassed)

A few day's ago, I downloaded the front-end code for the website from the VPN (GIT). I forgot to update the code-behind reference in the App.js file in the front end root. This, of course, referred to the API on the cloud, and not my local API.

This took me way to long to find out. But, at the same time, it's not a solution I've seen so far on the web.

Thanks for all your help.